# PHP - How to calculate the values ​of the second foreach loop?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a code that I am trying to make work but I just can't! 
I have 2 arrays: 1-> Diares 2-> The value corresponds to each diary entry.

```
$diarioNum =  array( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 3 [4] => 5 [5] => 1 [6] => 1 );
$vintoBookSX = array( [0] => -0.5 [1] => -0.4 [2] => -0.6 [3] => -0.4 [4] => -0.4 [5] => -1 [6] => -1 );
```

In my case I have multiply diaries and in the database from which I extrapolate the data are not in order, so I had to do this code:

```
<?php
    $con = array_count_values($diarioNum);
    foreach ($con as $key => $value) {  
     $pos = array_keys($diarioNum, $key);
     echo "Diario " .$key. "<br>";
      foreach ($pos as $ke => $val) {
        $vBKsx = $vintoBookSX[$val];
        echo $vBKsx . "<br>";       
      } 
   }
?>
```

Output:

```
Diario 1
-0.5
-0.6
-1
-1
Diario 2
-0.4
Diario 3
-0.4
Diario 5
-0.4
```

my Database table:
[my Database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4VxX.png)

Now I have to sum values ​​for each diary.
And then output it must be:

```
Diario 1
-3.1
Diario 2
-0.4
Diario 3
-0.4
Diario 5
-0.4
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Do your keys from `$diarioNum` match the values for `$vintoBookSX`?

Comment: yes, for each diary number i have corrispondent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to use a complicated way to do that, this is how I will do it (on PHP side):

```
$diarioNum =  [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1 ];
$vintoBookSX = [ -0.5, -0.4, -0.6, -0.4, -0.4, -1, -1 ];

$result = [];

foreach ($diarioNum as $k => $day) {
    $result[$day][] = $vintoBookSX[$k];
}

print_r($result);

$sums = array_map('array_sum', $result);

print_r($sums);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/hCVls)

There's probably a better way to do it on DBMS side. Something like:

```sql
SELECT diarioNumero, SUM(VintoBook_SX)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY diarioNumero
ORDER BY diarioNumero
```

Comment: It works! for the database question it is certainly the best way but I always try to save requests to db. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more solution

```
$diarioNum =  array(1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 1, 1 );
$vintoBookSX = array(-0.5, -0.4, -0.6, -0.4, -0.4, -1, -1 );

$result = array_fill_keys( array_unique($diarioNum), 0);

foreach ( $diarioNum as $key => $val ) {
    $result[ $val ] += $vintoBookSX[ $key ];
}
foreach ( $result as $key => $val ) {
    echo "Diario $key <br>";
    echo $val . "<br>";
}
```